# Spark Encoders.bean not working for generic class

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, encoder, apache-spark-encoders

I have a generic Java class

```
public class Person<T> {
    private String name;
    private List<T> attributes;
}

public class AttributeOne {
    // some fields
}

public class AttributeTwo {
    // some fields
}
```

and I want to convert from a Spark DataSet to a list of Java `Person<T>` objects. (each record of the input DataSet is converted to a `Person<T>` object).

I first tried passing the generic type "T" to the Encoder. Code is something like:

```
val ds = inputDS.map(<logic to convert input dataset to Person object>)(Encoders.bean(classOf[Person[T]]))

ds.write.json(...)
```

Code compiles and runs without error. But the output shows only the `name` field is successfully encoded, the generic `attributes` field is not. The output data looks like:

```
{"name": "name-1", "attributes": [{}, {}, {}]}
{"name": "name-2", "attributes": [{}, {}]}
...
```

This means the Encoder already recognized how many "attribute" elements because the `attributes` list is not empty, but each "attribute" element is empty `{}`.

I realized that Encoders needs to know the exact types at compile time to generate the serialization/deserialization code. A generic type parameter T is not enough information.

So I explicitly passed the exact type to the Encoder:

```
val ds = inputDS.map(<logic to convert input dataset to Person<AttributeOne> object>)(Encoders.bean(classOf[Person[AttributeOne]]))

ds.write.json(...)
```

However, result is exactly the same with passing generic type "T" - the `name` field is encoded but the generic `attributes` field is not (though the Encoder recognized how many "attribute" elements).

Any suggestions?